# Azure DevOps - Permission denied / Could not read from remote repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, cicd

I am trying to Build a CI/CD pipeline which will push code from my Azure DevOps Repo to an Ubuntu Azure VM server's local repo. I am using this below code -

I am getting this error when I run this pipeline -

> Trying to establish an SSH connection to ***@4.---.---.---:22
> Successfully connected. cd /webdata/www/apps/src git pull origin
> master  # Pulling changes from the remote master branch
> ##[error]Permission denied, please try again.
>
> ##[error]Permission denied, please try again.
>
> ##[error]git@ssh.dev.azure.com: Permission denied (password,publickey).
>
> ##[error]fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

How to resolve this?

Used this code in the yml file -

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: SSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'devops-pipeline-sc'
    runOptions: 'commands'
    sshCommonArgs: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
    commands: |
      cd /webdata/www/apps/src
      git pull origin master  # Pulling changes from the remote master branch
    readyTimeout: '20000'
```

Comment: You’re going to want to format this using markup to help your chances of having someone help. Also talk about what you’ve done to configure the git client auth on the VM to connect to ado

Comment: You will have to do authentications for your git also.

Comment: 1. Is the SSH key you use to create the SSH service connection the same as the [SSH key used to connect to the Azure repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)? 2. What's the result if you run git pull directly in your VM?